# Jupyter hide dataframe index but keep original stying

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

In Jupyter I would like to hide the index of a pandas dataframe. The below code successfully hides the index, but will print out the entire dataframe rather than default of printing just the first and last 5 rows. How can I hide the index but retain the default styling?

```py
df.style.hide_index()
```

Comment: Can you explain your question a little more? like first case, expected result bla bla.

Comment: I am not sure how to explain it more. The default behaviour in a Jupyter notebook is to print out the first 5 and last 5 rows of a dataframe. The above code successfully hides the index, but prints out the entire dataframe, where I would like to preserve the default behaviour of printing out the first 5 rows and last 5 rows.

Answer (score 0):

you could assign it first to a new data frame and only show the first 5  of it like that

```
df_new = df.style.hide_index()
df_new.head(self, n=5)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for explain.
You can use **set_index** function. Use "First_Column_Name" as parameter

```
df.set_index('First_Column_Name', inplace=True)
df
```

So the default behavior will be preserved.